# Bash String Comparison With Regex Not Working

Tags: sed, zsh

I'm trying to do a simple string comparison in zsh where one the arguments is the result of a *sed* call.

Yet I keep getting "*zsh: missing end of string*"

```
[ (sed -En s/'(^.+)-SNAPSHOT'/'\1'/p ./app_version.txt) = "1.20.11" ]
```

The app_version.txt file contains a Maven version. sed is stripping out "SNAPSHOT".
app_version.txt

> 1.20.11-SNAPSHOT

Comment: You are missing the `$` before `(sed ...`); also, it should be in double-quotes to avoid weird parsing problems (yes, even in zsh). And please don't confuse zsh with bash (or plain string comparison with regex).

Comment: @paiego : I don't understand the _title_ of your question. There is nothing bash-related in it. Also, aside the points mentioned by GordonDavisson, I don't see why you are reverting to _sed_ for extracting the version.

Comment: `grep -q '1.20.11-SNAPSHOT' ./app_version.txt`? I'm not sure why you are using `sed` and `test` here.

Comment: @chepner. app_version.txt is a maven version and may or may not contain "-SNAPSHOT". I just want to extract the Semantic version and compare that.

Comment: @GordonDavisson. The $() was needed, much appreciated. My original post said I was using "bash (actually zsh)" but that was edited out by someone else. This is string comparison in bash, yet I'm using regex to remove the "-SNAPSHOT" from the app_version.txt, using sed and regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the output of your `sed` needs to be double quoted. Try this:

```
[ "$(sed -En s/'(^.+)-SNAPSHOT'/'\1'/p ./app_version.txt)" = "1.20.11" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't even need regular expressions. You could do it with

```
 if [[ $(<app_version.txt) == 1.20.11-SNAPSHOT ]]
```

or, if you want to make the *SNAPSHOT* part optional, something like

```
 if [[ $(<app_version.txt) == 1.20.11-* ]]
```